# Joda Time, parse hours and clockhours at the same time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I want to have a DateTime Parser that can parse a time that is either in "normal" hours or in clockhours.
Means that I can have `00:00:00` or `24:00:00` at the same time.
Further clockhour is only allowed for midnight. Means `24:00:01` is not allowed. This must be expressed as `00:00:01`.
Is this somehow achievable?
My parser currently does not respect clockhours:

```
//The formatter for the timezone
DateTimeFormatter timezoneFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendTimeZoneOffset(null, true, 2, 2)
            .toFormatter();
//The formatter for the fractional (3 digit) seconds
DateTimeFormatter fractionalSecondsFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendLiteral('.')
            .appendFractionOfSecond(3, 3).toFormatter();

// Here a parser is created that parses a string of the form HH:mm:ss. Further the string may have
// 3 digit fractional seconds (with a dot as prefix) and may have a timezone.
DATE_TIME_PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendHourOfDay(2).appendMinuteOfHour(2).appendSecondOfMinute(2)
            .appendOptional(fractionalSecondsFormatter.getParser()).appendOptional(timezoneFormatter.getParser())
            .toFormatter();
```

Would be greate if someone could help me.

Best regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joda-Time does not support parsing of 24:00. If you want to parse that you'll need to implement `DateTimeParser` yourself and intergrate it using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

Clock hour 24 would equate to 23:00.  Using the format kk:mm:ss `24:00:01` would be allowed.  So in that sense `24:00:00` is never equal to `00:00:00`.

Comment: Regarding ISO 8601 (and xs:time) hours are described as: The two digits in a hh format can have values from 0 to 24. If the value of the hour element is 24 then the values of the minutes element and the seconds element must be 00 and 00. 24 cannot be equal to 23. Then the hours would be 21:00, 22:00, 24:00, 00:00. I want to map the ISO8601 hour format with Joda (in Joda, hh is 00 - 23 and kk is 01 - 24, but with kk 24:01 is allowed, with ISO8601 not)

Comment: I understand this as 24:00 is the same point in time as 00:00 but 24:00 the day before 00:00. 24:00 can (ISO8601) only be used to describe exactly midnight.